# System.Web.UI.Controls.ControlCollection.Add Throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a tabbed user interface using an asp:Panel and the asp:TreeView. I'm keeping both TreeViews initialized in the background and when I need to display one, I clear the panel and then add the appropriate TreeView.

I'm keeping the TreeView's stored in the Session variable so they don't go away when the page gets reloaded due to a postback.

But when I try to add the control, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Here's the small snippet of code that matters:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="ContentButton" OnClick="ContentButton_Click" Text="Contents" runat="server" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ContentButton" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div id="TOCPanel" runat="server" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here's the related code in the C# file.

```
protected void IndexButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    TOCPanel.Controls.Clear();
    // _TreeView points to a property that retrieves the TreeView from Session["TreeView"]
    TOCPanel.Controls.Add( _TreeView ); // This line fails
    // TOCPanel.Controls.Add( new TreeView() ); // This fails with the same error message too
}
```

Is there any reason

Comment: Do you get the same error when using an <asp:Panel /> instead of a div?

Comment: It does the same thing. But it seems to only crash when I change the control. So in initialization, I'm adding the first TreeView during the page load. After I press the button, I'm changing the control and it crashes. If I press the button on the one currently loaded, it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is, but I'd suggest adding both TreeViews to the ContentTemplate, and then hiding/showing them with the Visible property. This gets rid of your dependency on Session as well. I've found manually adding and removing controls gets messy, especially when dealing with ViewState.